# How to know if an Air France flight has in-flight entertainment?

Tags: air-travel, air-france

I have just booked a flight, from Paris CDG to Moscow SVO return. It is a 4 hour 10 minute flight. Usually when I travel on other airlines no entertainment is provided as the flight isn’t long enough.

When logging in to the My Booking page for Air France, I see this page:

[image: page]

At the top, I see *Newspapers and magazines*, whereas when scrolling down, I see *IN-Flight ENTERTAINMENT*. Which one is correct, do I have in-flight entertainment or not or both?

Some medium and short-haul flights also have in-flight entertainment:

> By the end of 2018, the in-flight Wi-Fi offer, Air France CONNECT, will be available on 22 long-haul aircraft and 8 short- and medium-haul aircraft, with an aim of equipping the entire fleet by the end of 2020.

([Source](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwiA2OCvirjkAhUbShUIHWHnAScQFjACegQIDRAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcorporate.airfrance.com%2Fen%2Fnews%2Fair-france-launches-its-new-flight-wi-fi-offer&usg=AOvVaw2NI43CmMkoo6unt40y3VZt))

How do I know if my flight has this?

My plane is an Airbus A321.

Comment: What plane type are you flying?

Comment: @jpatokal Airbus A321

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to figure what amenities your plane has is to use [SeatGuru](https://www.seatguru.com/).  First identify what plane you're flying (typically written in your booking somewhere), and then just hover over your seat in the seat maps.  In your case Air France has two types of Airbus A321s:

https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Air_France/Air_France_Airbus_A321_Europe.php

https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Air_France/Air_France_Airbus_A321_Metropole.php

[image: Example screenshot from Seatguru]

...but the "Europe" model has only "overhead TV", while the "Metropole" model has "No TV".

Obligatory disclaimer: Airlines reserve the right to swap planes with no notice, so you may not get inflight entertainment even if promised.  (Or, if you're *really* lucky, get it when you weren't supposed to!).

Answer (score 4):

I have checked the flights from Paris to Moscow with Air France and they are all typically operated on a A319, A320 or A321, none of which have in-flight entertainment such as TVs. They may have in-flight WiFi though, that will be either free or you must pay for.

Comment: Do you have any source regarding this and whether the WiFi will be free or not?

Comment: Yes. https://www.airfrance.co.uk/GB/en/local/resainfovol/horaires/tableauHoraires.do this shows all Air France flights from Paris to Moscow. https://www.mro-network.com/cabin-interiors-inflight-entertainment/air-france-orders-inflight-connectivity-a320-family-airliners this is an article explaining that Air France have ordered inflight WiFi on the A320-family planes (which includes the A321) and all their planes will be fitted with in-flight WiFi by the end of 2020. It's difficult to say if his flight will contain WiFi as it's still an on-going process.

Comment: I mean the fact it does not have in flight entertainment.

Comment: I didn't state it would or would not have in-flight entertainment. It's hard to say as it's an on-going process that Air France are still currently doing.

Comment: If I'm honest then I'm inclined to say it's unlikely it'll offer TV screens as A321s typically don't. The WiFi, however, is much more likely although bare in mind it's still an on-going process. Also, I know you booked via Air France but is your flight operated by Air France, or another airline?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98303/discussion-between-daniil-and-lr837).